# Method that takes an array and compacts it down

Tags: java, arrays

The assignment given was, write a program that reads numbers off of a file, construct an array from those numbers, and move all the zeroes to the end of the array.

For example.

Before: 0, 9, 7, 0, 0, 23, 4, 0

After: 9, 7, 23, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0

After toying with it for about 2 hours i came up with this.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Compactor{

Scanner in;
private int numNum = 0;

public void calcNumNum(){
    try{
        in = new Scanner(new File("compact.txt"));
        while(in.hasNext()){
            int dumpVal = in.nextInt();
            numNum++;
        }
        makeArray(numNum);
    }catch(IOException i){
        System.out.println("Error: " + i.getMessage());
    }
}

private void makeArray(int x){
    int i = 0;
    int[] arrayName = new int[x];
    try{
        in = new Scanner(new File("compact.txt"));
        while(i < x){
            arrayName[i] = in.nextInt();
            i++;
        }
        compact(arrayName);
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

private void compact(int[] x){
    int counter = 0;
    int bCounter = (x.length - 1);
    for(int j = 0; j < x.length; j++){
        if(x[j]!=0){
            x[counter] = x[j];
            counter++;
        }else{
            x[bCounter] = x[j];
            bCounter--;
        }
    }
    printArray(x);
}

private void printArray(int[] m){
    int count = 0;
    while(count < m.length){
        System.out.print(m[count] + "  ");
        count++;
    }
}
```

}

The file that was given to us was: 0, 6, 13, 0, 0, 75, 33, 0, 0, 0, 4, 2,9 21, 0, 86, 0, 32, 66, 0, 0.

What i got was: 6, 13, 75, 33, 4, 29, 21, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0. (without the commas of course, i just put those in for easier reading.)

Could anyone perhaps give me insight on how to fix this problem, or maybe i should just start my code over with a different approach, the whole,

```
if(x[j]!=0){
    x[counter] = x[j];
    counter++;
 }else{
    x[bCounter] = x[j];
    bCounter--;
 }
```

i just made it up on the fly, thinking it would work fine, obviously it kept on going after it got past the last value and kept setting more and more values counting backwards as zeroes, no idea how to make it work though, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: While not nice, you can actually use `sort` with an appropriate comparator.

Comment: `sort` only works if the order of non-zero elements can be changed, which was not mentioned in the question.

Comment: You really need a swap operation, not just an assignment. What happens to the old x[counter]?

Comment: How about you just count the number of zeros, don't add them to the array and add the appropriate amount of zeros after input processing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there with `compact()`:

```
private void compact(int[] x) {
    int counter = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < x.length; j++) {
        if (x[j] != 0) {
            x[counter++] = x[j];
        }
    }
    while (counter < x.length) {
        x[counter++] = 0;
    }
    printArray(x);
}
```

Comment: Or instead of the `while` to zero out the tail: `Arrays.fill(x, counter, x.length, 0);`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this problem is to create a secondary array of the same size, then do this:

Iterate through the first array. If the number is non-zero, put it into the second array, keeping a counter for the second array starting from 0, increasing by 1 whenever you add an element into it.

Since int arrays initialize to 0, after you go through the initial array once, you'll be done. The second array will hold the answer.

```
// create your initial array x the same way as before

int[] y = new int[x.length];
int counter = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

   if(x[i] != 0) {

      y[counter] = x[i];
      counter++;
   }
}
```

Comment: That is what i would have done in the first place but we're not allowed to do that in this assignment.

Answer (score 0):

This part looks reasonable

```
for(int j = 0; j < x.length; j++){
    if(x[j]!=0){
        x[counter] = x[j];
        counter++;
    }

}
```

It puts all non-zero elements into the beginning of the array. The problem is the else-part, which overwrites elements at the end of the array. Since you already know that only zeros belong to the end of the array, just fill the array with zeros, beginning at `counter`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do in following simple way also : (It consist of logic for changes in array. As reading from file and storing in array is pretty clear to u.)

```
package SO;

public class ZeroAtEnd {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = new int[] { 0, 6, 13, 0, 0, 75, 33, 0, 0, 0, 4, 2, 9, 21, 0, 86, 0, 32, 66, 0, 0 };
    arr = makeZeroAtEnd(arr);
}

    private static int[] makeZeroAtEnd(int[] arr) {
    int l = arr.length;
    int leftCounter = 0;
    int rightCounter = l - 1;
    int[] finalArr = new int[l];
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == 0) {
        // put at end
        finalArr[rightCounter] = arr[i];
        rightCounter--;
        } else {
        // put at beginning.
        finalArr[leftCounter] = arr[i];
        leftCounter++;
        }
    }
    for (int i : finalArr)
        System.out.println(i);
    return finalArr;
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
6
13
75
33
4
2
9
21
86
32
66
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```